# Why does UnityWebRequest return unkown error when I do a GET request on Linux?

Tags: linux, firebase, unity-game-engine, web, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code:

```
public class DatabaseHandler : MonoBehaviour
{

    string url = "https://fakeid.firebaseio.com/";
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetLevelsCoroutine());
    }

    IEnumerator GetLevelsCoroutine()
    {    
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {
            www.SetRequestHeader("X-Firebase-Decoding", "1");
            yield return www.SendWebRequest();
            if (www.isDone)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
                string result = www.downloadHandler.text;
                Debug.Log(result);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

The result variable is null and the www.error is "unknown error"
I have been trying different things in order to fix this but, I just can't figure out what's causing this error, since it's just a generic error.

I have also read that this may be an unitywebrequest bug, if it is so, are there any alternatives?

Comment: Can also be an authentication error or a server internal error. You should also check the `www.responseCode` to see what kind of error you actually get.

Comment: www.responseCode returns 0

Comment: So maybe your server isn't even found / not responding on that url

Comment: Yes you are right, in fact it works with www.google.com, I am following this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAxZPgBRCmARIsAOrTHSYLXp2aF42RLrv_-t_Yu3wkw1TGQ4FrttjYEJzXUMhlBmamZOIEn1saAk5nEALw_wcB

Comment: Is there a reason actually against using [firebase SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53597396/why-does-unitywebrequest-return-unkown-error-when-i-do-a-get-request)?

Comment: Firebase SDK doesn't currently support Desktop production apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found the solution to the problem. (It only occurs on some Linux OS)

Unity only officially supports Ubuntu Linux, so it is looking (and failing to find) the certificate store where it would expect it to be. You can work around on Fedora by creating a symbolic link:

```
mkdir -p /etc/ssl/certs && ln -s /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
```

This is the source where I got it from: https://forum.unity.com/threads/ubuntu-headless-build-tls-handshake-fails.546704/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're trying to get JSON from the Firebase Realtime Database through its REST API. Requests to the REST API must end in `.json`, otherwise Firebase interprets them as requests to open the console on that location. So `UnityWebRequest.Get(url+.json)`

Comment: My new url is: "https://fakeid.firebaseio.com/levels.json" but this didn't fix the problem